# Connecting Android application with Remote oracle database 10g or 11g without JDBC

Tags: java, android, oracle

I have seen many tutorials as well as many questions related to connection of an android application with remote MySQL Database using RESTFUL web service like

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/restful-web-services-with-java.htmlm,

http://avilyne.com/?p=105,

http://www.programmingrelief.com/2960978/Android-Apps---Web-Services-In-Java-Instead-Of-Php-To-Connect-To-Mysql-Database .

But I am not able to get anything about connecting the  application to Remote Oracle database.

I don't want to use JDBC in this.

Can you suggest me any tutorial for this?

Comment: I am sensing from your question that you want to make a direct connection to the oracle database and run SQL queries on it. In a nutshell, this can't be done, you will need an intermediary server side language such as Java or PHP for this which will use a driver supplied by Oracle to connect to the database.

Comment: can you give me any sample tutorial for the same? Most preferably java

Comment: As @jax mentioned, soemthing is going to have to make that database connection.  If you want to make RESTful calls from your Andriod program, then the RESTful service is probably the code that will be making a database connection.  Either you write a RESTful api that connects to a database and returns the data you want OR you connect to someone else RESTful API and they will return data to you.  Make sense?

Comment: I don't know how to use webservice for connecting to oracle in android. Can you just give a tutorial link?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u to use Oracle REST Data Services.
 try this : [Oracle Documentation for REST Service](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html#about_oracle_application_express) and this : [Native Oracle XML DB Web Services](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/native-oracle-xml-db-web-services-11gr1.php)